# where to go to give permission to users?

Tags: odoo

someone knows how to give permission to users created in odoo. It turns out that I already do all the code but I do not know where to go in the odoo system to be able to grant her permission. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Settings >> Users & Companies` and select the user.
Choose the Access restriction for apps from the Application Accesses menu .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can give permission to user two ways:

1. Settings --> Users & Companies --> Users --> Select User
2. your module/security/ir.model.access.csv
   id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink

Comment: Can just only one way set permission? or need to set both?

Comment: You need to set it only one way.

Comment: but how can odoo know which group that user belongs to by 1. and which user have the permission by 2.?

Comment: 1) you have to be select group for user in user screen then user automatically added in that group.
2) you giving permission to that group (group_id mention) permission apply for whole group CRUD, (1,1,1,1) is full permission.